# Error checking for SDK components

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I've installed the latest version of Android Studio, but there's a problem. When I run this software, I can see a window that lets me know Android Studio's checking for updated SDK components, while the following error message is displayed:

> The following SDK components were not installed: extra-android-m2repository, extra-google-m2repository and tools

How can I fix it? I've tried to follow another posts from StackOverflow, but I cannot find a solution. Additionaly, the JVM is installed.

Comment: Why do you think you need to fix it? Why don't you simply ignore the message and proceed with developing your application as usual?

Comment: I thought I could have another older problems which forced me to reinstall Android Studio. Yet, thanks for your help, @yole